# Parsing String to Date without using SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting, date-parsing

I am developing a spring application and in one of my controller i have following lines to parse from string to date and format the parsed date to required format. But again i need to parse back formatted string into date without using any SimpleDateFormat, so is it possible to do so ?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date pick=dateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("pickDate"));
String pick_date=dateFormat2.format(pick);
```

Comment: what is the problem with using SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Why can't you use `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: You should avoid using SimpleDataFormat, because It's not thread-safe.

Comment: then you can have a local date format object, instead of sharing one across threads

Comment: I don't see a valid reason for not using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar, there is no problem with it. But just I need to know how that can be done without using any Date Formatters that's it.

Comment: Well then you shall reimplement something like it (maybe with fixed patterns) yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

> I found in the wikipedia that china has the locale yyyy-MM-dd. check this reference [date format by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)
>   set locale to China you'll get the required date format

Try this

```
String d1="12-27-2010";
    Stirng[] splitdata=d1.split("-");

   int month=Integer.parseInt(splitdata[0]);
 int day=Integer.parseInt(splitdata[1]);
int year=Integer.parseInt(splitdata[2]);

Calender cal=Calender.getInstance(Locale.CHINA);
cal.set(year,month,day);
Date d=cal.getTime();
```

This should work

---

If you know your data format  you can do that. by using simple string operations

Ex:
if your data format is

> MM-dd-yyyy

then you can convert to `yyyy-MM-dd` like this

```
String d1="12-27-2010";
Stirng[] splitdata=d1.split("-");

String s2= splitdate[2]+"-"+splitdate[0]+"-"+splitdate[1];
```

Comment: But how you will parse it back to Date?. 's2' in your example is just string not Date object.

Comment: @WannabeGeek Sorry for the late reply and also wrong answer. I will get back to you in a min

Comment: I appreciate your effort, thanks for the answer. I will try your answer and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Concatenation Operator(+) for that

Answer (score -2):

Yes possible; just write the code to do the parsing. Should not be that difficult ...

Comment: how to do it without using SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: just like how you program any other stuff. Pick up the string, break it up, 'read' the string, make a date out of it. I mean if you are NOT to use the inbuilt libraries of the language, you got to implement it yourself. Whoever wrote SimpleDateFormat did write the parsing code. You can write something similar. And a web search should yield you sample code as well.

But it is most of the time a futile exercise .... difficult to get it right. What exactly is the problem with SimpleDateFormat ?